# SQL Count Values From the Top 6

Tags: mysql

i trying to create an SQL query to count how many times [Over]='Y' in the Top 6 selection and i receive an error in the merge query.

Query to get Top 6:

```
 SELECT TOP 6 [Number]
  ,[Over]
  ,[Goal]
 FROM [Test_Hermes].[dbo].[Test]
 ORDER BY Number desc
```

Query to count:

```
SELECT COUNT([Over]) 
FROM [dbo].[Test] 
WHERE [OVER] = 'Y';
```

Merge both queries:

```
SELECT COUNT([Over]) 
FROM (SELECT TOP 6 [Number]
  ,[Over]
  ,[Goal]
FROM [Test_Hermes].[dbo].[Test]
ORDER BY Number desc) 
WHERE [OVER] = 'Y';
```

any help will be appreciate!
Thanks

Comment: It looks like MsSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show this sample pls.

```
 SELECT
   [Number]
  ,[Over]
  ,[Goal]
  , SUM( If(OVER= 'Y',1,0)) AS CNT
 FROM [Test_Hermes].[dbo].[Test]
 ORDER BY Number desc
LIMIT 1,6;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an order by in a sub query.

```
SELECT COUNT([t1].[Over]) 
FROM (SELECT TOP 6 [Number]
    ,[Over] 
    ,[Goal]
  FROM [Test_Hermes].[dbo].[Test]) as t1
WHERE [OVER] = 'Y' ;
```

If you need the order to determine the top 6 use ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT COUNT([t1].[Over]) 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Number] ORDER BY [Number] DESC) as 'Rank'
    ,[Number]
    ,[Over] 
    ,[Goal]
  FROM [Test_Hermes].[dbo].[Test]) as t1 

WHERE [t1].[OVER] = 'Y' AND [t1].[Rank] <= 6;
```

Comment: the first query looks to work ok but the second one result an error in the line 'WHERE [Rank] <= 6) as t1 ' with the word RANK to be underline

Comment: Ah. I had that too soon, it needs to be part of the where after that table is created and not when it is created.  It should be fixed now